# Node readdirSync and getting paths dynamically

Tags: node.js, image, npm, readdir

I have a directory whose contents shrink and grow. I am trying to run a program that will list all the directories.

Is there a way for `fs.readdirSync` to be fed a path like `./src/images/*/*/*` and it would list all the paths within that wildcard structure?

The only alternative I can see is creating some complex nested loops.

Comment: Surely there are packages available that will do just that.

Comment: Not for my purposes

Comment: These all seem like you should be able to use them: [`read-dir-deep`](https://github.com/chrisblossom/read-dir-deep), [`fdir`](https://github.com/thecodrr/fdir), [`file-matcher`](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/file-matcher).